# How to make a loop repeat itself n number of times - Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started programming 2 weeks ago for the first time in my life and I have come across something that I cannot figure out. I am trying to make it so a loop that calculates a median from a set amount of random numbers can repeat itself many times (say 10,000) while storing all the median values into a list. I already have everything up to the point where a list is created from the random integers (numbList) from which the median (listMedian) is calculated. I would just like to be able to repeat this process a number of times while generating a list of all the calculated medians. Sample size is how many numbers that are per list and upper limit determines what the range is for each individual number, thanks! I am using Python 3.

```
import random


def median(numbList):

    srtd = sorted(numbList)
    mid = len(numbList)//2
    if len(numbList) % 2 == 0:
        return (srtd[mid-1] + srtd[mid]) / 2.0
    else:
        return srtd[mid]


sampleSize = int(input("What is your desired sample size? "))

upperLimit = int(input("What is your desired upper limit? "))

numbList = []

totalMedians = []

biggerList = []


while sampleSize > 0:

    sampleSize -= 1

    randomNum = random.randrange(0,upperLimit+1)

    numbList.append(randomNum)

    numbList.sort(key=int)

    listMedian = median(numbList)
```

Comment: Just put the whole thing inside another loop, e.g. `for i in range(n):`.

Comment: I tried that by doing `totalMedians.append(listMedian)` but each numbList was the exact same. I can't make it so each numbList is different.

Comment: @user3238946 Please include all of the relevant code (e.g. where do `numbList` and `totalMedians` come from?) in your question.

Comment: Because you're not resetting the list each time. Add something like `numbList = []` after `while sampleSize > 0:`. Make a list of lists if you actually want to keep each `numbList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example of what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random

def create_list(sampleSize, upperLimit):
    numbList = []
    while sampleSize > 0:
        sampleSize -= 1
        randomNum = random.randrange(0,upperLimit+1)
        numbList.append(randomNum)
    numbList.sort(key=int)
    return numbList

def median(numList):
    list_len = len(numList)
    if list_len % 2:
        return numList[list_len / 2]
    else:
        return (numList[list_len / 2] + numList[list_len / 2 - 1]) / 2.0

def main():
    number_lists = 4
    sample_size = 5
    upper_limit = 50
    lists = []
    median_list = []

    for i in range(number_lists):
        lists.append(create_list(sample_size, upper_limit))

    for current_list in lists:
        current_median = median(current_list)
        print current_list, " : median (", current_median, ")"
        median_list.append(current_median)

    print "Median list is ", median_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

which outputs, for example:

```
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$ ./sample.py
[3, 18, 20, 26, 46]  : median ( 20 )
[18, 22, 38, 44, 49]  : median ( 38 )
[28, 29, 34, 42, 43]  : median ( 34 )
[4, 21, 27, 31, 46]  : median ( 27 )
Median list is  [20, 38, 34, 27]
paul@MacBook:~/Documents/src/scratch$
```

Comment: Thank you, we haven't started learning the def command but now I see what it does. Thanks again my man.

Answer (score 0):

say you have this

```
print ('hello')
```

to loop it you would need to add :  `for #1 in range(#2)`:    at the start     (#1 any variable, #2 how many times it will repeat)

for example

```
for somevariable in range(3)
print('hello')

hello
hello
hello
```